# Pause automatic run of rtvscan.exe (Symantec AntiVirus)

Tags: anti-virus

While sitting on computer at work, occasionally some automatic antivirus scanning starts, trashing disk and making my machine unresponsive. I would like to pause this activity until I leave for the day. Is there any way to do this? I do not find anything listed as "Scheduled Scans" in the antivirus client. The about dialouge says `Full version, 10.1.4.4000.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correctly configured rtvscan allows you to pause it for 1 or 3 hours, up to 3 times. This helps in most cases.

Or, you can just kill it. Ctrl + Shift + Esc to open the task manager, go to the applications tab (not processes!) and kill the scanner. It will wait a few seconds without actually reacting, but then will ask you if you're sure to end the application. Answer yes, and that's it.

Comment: Killing it solves my problem. It does not pop up with any confirmation dialogue though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permissions to kill processes, you can kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that rtvscan is actually the **r**eal **t**ime **v**irus **scan**ner and is always on. This is why you cannot find it under scheduled scans as it does not occur periodically but constantly.
If you do manage to stop it from functioning, you will leave yourself vulnerable.

The following quote is from www.liutilities.com

> The rtvscan.exe file runs the real-time scanning feature of the Symantec Internet Security Suite and is responsible for detecting malicious code embedded on possible viruses and other malware processes. When a file enters the system, the rtvscan.exe file will automatically execute and scan the file, immediately notifying the user about any files it detects. The rtvscan.exe file can also automatically clean the infected file. For the full protection of your computer, the file rtvscan.exe runs continuously in order to check every file that enters your system. Aside from scanning and notifying the user about virus infections, it also logs or saves a report every time it performs a scan. The log or report details the information about the file scanned, its location, and the virus that came bundled with the file along with the actions taken by both the user and the program about the security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your machine or a corporate machine? If it is a corp machine and it is set up properly then there is nothing that you can do to change it. You can ask the SAV Admin to.